# How to show data on different columns in Reactjs based on weekday

Tags: reactjs

Hi I have an Reactjs application , it's a simple todo application where the user can add todo and this app will show the todos only for one week like from Monday-sunday. Now I need to display the todos on seperate columns based on weekday like if the todos has been added on Monday it should show on Monday column.i tried conditional rendering ,is there any other best approach to implement this.

```
Todos=[{name:"trave", created_at:"Friday"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hmh... All I could recommend is first filtering the data to separate the weekdays then in rendering just render them. But I guess the best approach would be to update the backend to return already properly structured array where data is already separated.

Comment: Lith : My question is how can I show in ui.If I seperate the data

Comment: Here is a quick exmaple I made for you :) https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-easley-weifl?file=/src/App.js Hope it helps. Feel free to ask any questions if you have any about that code